# How do you display just the body text of a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the value of just the text of a Wordpress post(only the text area) but can't seem to figure out how to do so without pulling the date catergory etc... in the text.

Comment: Please post code. What have you tried? How are you "pulling the date category etc..."?

Comment: I have currently tried using get_the_content(), and the_content( ) to no avail. I am a novice when it comes to wordpress what I am trying to do is get just what is typed and no meta data at all.

Comment: Again, please post your code. It's going to be nearly impossible to help you if you don't post your code.